# How to make flexbox size each image according to it's size when their pre-defined size is the same?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am asking a question that seem simple but I've been stuck on it for 4 hours now without hope.
I am not sure if the problem is in the way I set up the image or flexbox settings.

I am using icons library in my project with the following settings:

```
 @mixin icon($url) {
    height: 4rem;
    width: 4rem;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: url($url);
    object-fit: contain;
    display: block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And then each icon looks like that:

```
.google-icon {
    @include icon('local address');
}
```

And I am trying to create a bootstrap card footer that contains these icons, in changing order. Now, the icons are not all the same size, but if I delete the height and width flexbox renders this space as 0x0px and so nothing shows inside
What I am trying to get is that these images will be shown side by side, without padding in between for when one icon was smaller than the other. I want them to be stretched, as much as they can in this footer, without extending from there or overlapping each other. And also for them to be in the middle of of the Y axis.

How can I do this?
Here's an [example](https://www.codeply.com/p/zeqT1xNSGE)

Edit:
Thank you @Pauli_D
The HTML to produce this problem is:

```
    <div class="card h-100">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer d-flex">
      <div>
          <i class="github-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
          <i class="google-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
          <i class="stackoverflow-icon"></i>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

where each icon follows the above CSS with different url.

Anyway, the solution was to change the display="block" to display="inline-block", and to ditch the divs, and just put all the icons inside as plain icons. normal line of text. And flexbox no-wrap behavior gets the desired result.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I see @Paulie_D thank you, I have manage to solve this problem evantually. But i'll know for the future

Answer (score -1):

the solution was to change the display="block" to display="inline-block", and to ditch the divs, and just put all the icons inside as plain icons. normal line of text. And flexbox no-wrap behavior gets the desired result.